# Can sphinx validate documentation against the actual implementation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm adding sphinx documentation to a couple of projects, but I'm concerned that down the line future developers aren't going to be rigorous in updating documentation when the method interface changes. Is there a way to have sphinx validate the list of arguments being described against what is actually specified in the method definition?

For example, let's say I set up sphinx using sphinx-quickstart, added autodoc, and am trying to build the following "module":

```
def product(arg_one, arg_two):
    '''
    :param arg_one: an object to be multiplied by arg_two
    :type arg_one: Object

    :param arg_two: an integer which defines the number of arg_one to return
    :type arg_two: integer

    :returns: The product of arg_one and arg_two

    :raises: TypeError
    '''
    return arg_one * arg_two
```

And, a week from now, Bob Doe updates product as follows:

```
def product(value, number, catch_errors=False):
    '''
    :param arg_one: an object to be multiplied by arg_two
    :type arg_one: Object

    :param arg_two: an integer which defines the number of arg_one to return
    :type arg_two: integer

    :returns: The product of arg_one and arg_two

    :raises: TypeError
    '''
    try:
        return value * number
    except TypeError as exc:
        if catch_errors:
            return None
        raise
```

Now, the sphinx documentation isn't correct - it's missing the new catch_errors field and the variables have been renamed. But, running

```
sphinx-build . ./_build
```

a second time doesn't catch the problems - it just reports

```
Running Sphinx v1.6.5
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
build succeeded.
```

I would expect (or hope) that Sphinx is capable of validating the docstring against the actual code of the method, and failing (or at least indicating in some way) when the documentation and the implementation aren't in-sync.

If sphinx isn't capable of this, is there an alternative which is? I know there's [function annotations in Python 3](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), but we're currently supporting both Python 2 and Python 3, so this isn't an option.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this exact problem, but if you're interested in validating documented examples, python's `doctest` module does that, is easy to use, and supports both python [2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

Answer (score 1):

After some looking, I think the closest tool I could find easily is [darglint](https://github.com/terrencepreilly/darglint) but it was recently put into archive-mode on Github (December 2022) so long term support is not guaranteed or even likely.

One option, inspired by [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3003) discussion from torchvision is to use [Sphinx-Napoleon](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pydocstyle](https://pydocstyle.org/en/stable/) with almost everything turned off, except `D417` which is a check for missing arguments in the docstring.

So `pydocstyle` can check for *missing* arguments but it cannot currently check for extra arguments.

Edit: seems pylint can do this with an extension https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/checkers/extensions.html#pylint-extensions-docparams but there is some functional overlap between the various linters and style checkers so you might need to just pick which ones you go with.

For catching re-named arguments, you could also enforce 100% coverage in your tests, but that wouldn't catch refactors to non-keyword arguments.

Of some other packages available:

[doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#) is good for checking if your docstring examples run correctly, but it doesn't do any signature validation. So if you set a default parameter like the example in the question, it will still pass doctest. If you used keyword arguments for all your examples, you could use this as a check, but it's a bit verbose.

[interrogate](https://interrogate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is capable of checking docstring coverage, but not much else (as far as I can tell?) I'm not sure whether other tools actually check coverage though, so this is potentially a good tool to use in tandem.